# ./configure: No such file or directory cygwin Freeglut

Tags: cygwin, configure, freeglut

I'm trying to generate the lib files for freeglut library. I've installed cygwin and according to README file that comes with the library,

```
Building and Installing the Libraries with Cygwin
=================================================

To build "freeglut" under Cygwin, you have two choices:

- You can build a normal Cygwin library, which depends on Cygwin's X11
  libraries. To do this, you can just use the normal autotools incantation:
      ./configure && make install

- Alternatively, you can build a DLL which does not depend on X11 and links
  against the opengl32 DLL. To do this, configure need a few more flags:
      ./configure CPPFLAGS=-mno-cygwin LDFLAGS=-mno-cygwin --without-x && make install


If you don't have MSVC, Open Watcom or Cygwin
=============================================
```

But If I run `./configure`, I got this error

```
$ ./configure CPPFLAGS=-mno-cygwin LDFLAGS=-mno-cygwin --without-x && make install
-bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

Is there something I need to install in order to solve this issue? The contents of the folder doesn't have configure. These are the files in the folder

[image]

Comment: it seems the README is obsolete. The presence of CMakeList suggests they moved to `cmake`

Comment: @matzeri, but the last update is in 2016!

Comment: but the README.cygwin is dated 2012..

Answer (score 1):

If you need freeglut, you need to install the cygwin package `libglut-devel`

Looking inside `setup.ini` you will find its description:

> libglut-devel
>   sdesc: "OpenGL Utility Toolkit library"
>   ldesc: "freeglut
>   is a completely OpenSourced alternative to the OpenGL Utility Toolkit
>   (GLUT) library. GLUT was originally written by Mark Kilgard to support
>   the sample programs in the second edition OpenGL 'RedBook'. Since
>   then, GLUT has been used in a wide variety of practical applications
>   because it is simple, widely available and highly portable. GLUT (and
>   hence freeglut) allows the user to create and manage windows
>   containing OpenGL contexts on a wide range of platforms and also read
>   the mouse, keyboard and joystick functions."
>   category: X11